# Unity: the sprite won't die on my cactus. Why?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

So, I want the game to go to Level 2 when the sprite in the suit collides with the cactus.

Why won't this work? This code is attached to the cacti.

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D(collider : Collider2D) {
    Application.LoadLevel(2);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try OnTriggerEnter2D , and put this function inside the cactus .

Comment: I tried this. It is updated up top, and it still won't load level 2.

Comment: remove application.loadlevel , print out a debug.log to see if its even working

Comment: Exactly my problem. It won't register the collision.

Comment: ok make sure one of them have a rigidbody2d component and use an if statement to check player name and if its correct print something to check if its working.

Comment: Can you give me an example of that in your answer?

Comment: void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.tag == "Player"){}
    }

Comment: Thank You! I just needed the Rigidbody2D on cactus